# How to calculate an invoice with canceled items?

Tags: collection, invoice, sales-order, grand-total

I have a order with canceled order items in it.
As an example:
Item 1 = 10 euro
Item 2 = 20 euro
Item 3 = 30 euro

Now the items 2 and 3 are canceled.
The grand_total should now be 10 Euro.

But when I create an invoice programmatically the invoice is always 60 euro.

To create my invoice I create a new Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order and use this for my invoice. But inside that model there are also the canceled items and so my invoice is always wrong.

Comment: What's the code you programmatically create your invoice with? The `prepareInvoice` method in the Order model knows which items are canceled, see `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item::getQtyToInvoice`

Comment: Sorry my fault. The quantity is correct. The problem is the total. In my invoice I only see the confirmed item but the total is from all items.

Comment: I think this is why Magento will cancel the whole order and create a new order with just the products needed, then you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

Magento creates always an invoice with all items and creditmemos with the canceled ones, together you get the sums you expect.